# Does multiple GenericKeyedObjectPools use the same eviction thread?

Tags: java, apache-commons-pool

If I'm using more than one [`GenericKeyedObjectPool`](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html) in an application with enabled asynchronous idle object eviction how many "idle object eviction" thread will run in the background?

Do multiple `GenericKeyedObjectPool`s create only one eviction thread or do they create separate threads for every pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The current implementation (v1.6) uses a static timer](http://commons.apache.org/pool/xref/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/EvictionTimer.html#42), so in practice multiple pools use only one eviction thread. ([Assuming that they are loaded into the same classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/225914/843804).) You can check it with `jstack`, there is only one timer thread:

```
"Timer-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x7bce5000 nid=0x1ca5 in Object.wait() [0x7b23d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xa26c0fe8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
    - locked <0xa26c0fe8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```